# Create a service that shows availability using if else state

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, class-diagram

)
I have the following code:

```
    class order {
        constructor(gameName, qty, remQty, available){
            this.gameName = gameName
            this.qty = qty;
            this.remQty = remQty;
            this.available = available;
        }
        function() { 
            if (this.available == 0) {
                return " is available" 
            } else {
                return  " is not available" 
            }
        }
    };
    let order = new order ('Call of Duty', '?', '?','?')
    let order = new order ('FIFA 21', '?', '?','?')
    let order = new order ('Crash Bandicoot', '?', '?','?')
    
    
    console.log(order1)
```

My question is, I am new to JavaScript and I can not make it work. I want to make a program which shows if a game is available given a quantity(stock) and if it is, my code shall respond with 'is available' else 'not available' and depending on the given order the remaining quantity shall change. Please help me, if further questions I will happily answer.

Comment: In your case is an `Order` actually ordering a product, from a stock of sorts? Or is the `Order` the stock itself? Sidenote: in JavaScript object constructors are written with a uppercased letter. This is a way of telling what the name represents and that you should use the `new` keyword (in most cases).

Comment: @emielZuurbier it is the stock itself. I am not trying to implement a system that has a major stock of any kind. It is just a simple system that shows a customer has made an order on 'this game' is it available or not? You feel me?

Comment: I see. Should the quantity drop whenever someone asks if an order is available? Why are most arguments filled in with question marks?

Comment: If possible, yes. As I am new to this, I would like answers from more experienced writers on whether this is appropriate or I should just stick to stock = 1 or 0.

Comment: Filled with questionmarks as I dont know what to write there

Comment: Got it! Thanks for answering. Last one: what's the difference between the quantity and the remaining quantity?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking of it like a store had a limited amount of 10 FIFA games for example, and for every order the 'remaining quantity' dropped. But i think I will forget about the remaing quantity as it gets way too hard for me, and just focus on writing a code that hardcodes a store has 1 or 0 in stock. You're welcome, hope you understood :/

Comment: Any feedback on the solution I've posted?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt was actually quite close, even more complex than it has to be. Lose some of the parameters, `remQty` and `available` can go. The quanity will simply be determined with a single number that decrements after polling each time for availability.

I named the function *where the magic happens* `getAvailability`. This name suggests that we *get* the *availability* of the order wer're working with.

Inside of it you want to know: is something available. That answer can be determined by checking how many of our quantity is left. We can do that by checking if the quantity [is greater than zero `> 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than).

```
if (this.qty > 0) {
  // Quantity is more than 0.
} else {
  // Quantity is not more than 0.
}
```

Here you will return the different strings with the availability text. To give it some polish, it would be nice to inject the name of the game in the string using *interpolation*, which is a fancy word for combining variables and strings.

The easiest way to do this is with [Template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You probably know that strings work with either `' '` or `" "`, but this one works with backticks `` ` ` ``. Inside of that string you can place variables like so:

```
// this.gameName refers to the same gameName used in the constructor.
`${this.gameName} is available`;
```

Now before returning your string (which will end function) you need to modify the quantity of your order. That means subtracting `this.qty` with 1. This can be done with by a decrement assignment:

```
// We assign a new value..
this.qty = this.qty - 1;

// ..this does the same, but is shorter.
this.qty -= 1;
```

or with a [decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement)

```
// This is also the same, but here it always decrements with 1.
this.qty--;
```

Now all you have to do is to call the `getAvailability` method (calling means running the function, method means function that is part of an object) and check the response it returned.

You can output variables and returned values with [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log). Make this tool your friend. It will shine light on places of darkness and will help you figure out your next steps.

Examine the example below which has all these principles put together. Feel free to ask any questions to have. And welcome to the wondrous world of JavaScript.

```js
class Order {
  constructor(gameName, qty) {
    this.gameName = gameName;
    this.qty = qty;
  }

  getAvailability() {
    if (this.qty > 0) {
      this.qty--;
      return `${this.gameName} is available`;
    } else {
      return `${this.gameName} is not available`;
    }
  }
};

let codOrder = new Order('Call of Duty', 5);
let fifaOrder = new Order('FIFA 21', 2);
let crashBandicootOrder = new Order('Crash Bandicoot', 1);

console.log( codOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( codOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( codOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( codOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( codOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( codOrder.getAvailability() );

console.log( fifaOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( fifaOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( fifaOrder.getAvailability() );

console.log( crashBandicootOrder.getAvailability() );
console.log( crashBandicootOrder.getAvailability() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class was close to working, I polished it up in this repl you can use to play around with it:

```
class Order {
    constructor(gameName, qty, remQty, available){
        this.gameName = gameName
        this.qty = qty;
        this.remQty = remQty;
        this.available = available;
    }
    isAvailable() { 
        if (this.available === 0) {
            return " is available" 
        } else {
            return  " is not available" 
        }
    }
};
const order1 = new Order ('Call of Duty', '?', '?', 0)
const order2 = new Order ('FIFA 21', '?', '?', 1)
const order3 = new Order ('Crash Bandicoot', '?', '?', 0)


order1.isAvailable()
order2.isAvailable()
```

https://repljs.com/tore/Wv1oxWPWV